# Adjust so that the week names change into an R code

Tags: r

I would like to know if there is a way to rename the weekday name information in a database. I have inserted the database I want to change below.

```
 df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2021-06-30", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-02", "2021-07-03","2021-07-04","2021-07-05","2021-07-06"),
 Week = c("Quarta-feira", "Quinta-feira", "Sexta-feira", "Sábado","Domingo","Segunda-feira","Terça-feira")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

I would like to make the following change instead of `Quarta-feira` I would just like `Quarta`, `Quinta-feira` to `Quinta`, `Sexta-feira` to `Sexta`, `Segunda-feira` to `Segunda`, `Terça-feira` to `Terça`, `Sábado`and `Domingo` remain the same.

Note: these days of the week are written in Portuguese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stringr` package in R to achieve the end result you want.
There's a function called `str_replace` in `stringr` package.

The syntax of `str_replace` is: `str_replace(string, pattern, replacement)`

In your case you can use the following code:

Notice that I haven't used 3 arguments and used only two as I've used pipeline.

```
library(stringr)

df1$Week <- df1$Week %>%
  str_replace("-.*", "")
```

This code will give you output like this:

```
        date    Week
1 2021-06-30  Quarta
2 2021-07-01  Quinta
3 2021-07-02   Sexta
4 2021-07-03  Sábado
5 2021-07-04 Domingo
6 2021-07-05 Segunda
7 2021-07-06   Terça
```

**EDIT**
To replace `Sábado` with `Sabado` you'll need to add another `str_replace` using pipeline structure.
The code will look like this:

```
df1$Week <- df1$Week %>%
  str_replace("-.*", "") %>%
  str_replace("Sábado", "Sabado")
```

Output:

```
        date    Week
1 2021-06-30  Quarta
2 2021-07-01  Quinta
3 2021-07-02   Sexta
4 2021-07-03  Sabado
5 2021-07-04 Domingo
6 2021-07-05 Segunda
7 2021-07-06   Terça
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,  that's it. Just one thing that I saw now, only `Sábado` that I saw is without accent, ie I would need to change `Sábado` to `Sabado`, can I adjust this along with your code?

Comment: I've edited my answer! Please accept it as an answer by clicking the tick button on the left and upvoting if I've solved your issue. That'll help me!